# Wireshark on a Citrix Client

Tags: wireshark, citrix

I'm working on an app which needs to intercept SSL from a Citrix client and write to a log file. We are trying to use Wireshark to log the traffic per this article:

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116557

However, I don't know where the certificate file is located on the client machine. Has anyone got this to work, and if so, what was the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what the target operating system was, that's running behind citrix.

However, assuming it's windows based:

In Win7/Server 2008

goto: Control Panel -> Internet options (Maybe internet & network then internet option on win7)

Either way, the dialogue box your looking for is the one that usually appears when you go "tools->options" in internet explorer.

Goto the "Content" tab, then click "Certificates" select the certificate you wish to export, then click "Export" and follow the instructions in the export wizard to save your certificate to disk.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. It's a windows 7 box, a user's workstation.

Comment: There's a bunch of certs in my local store, but I don't know which one is used by citrix. And ideas?

Comment: Off the top of my head, no I'm afraid not, and unfortunately I don't have access to a citrix box to look. Sorry.